# Run script when a folder or file is created

Tags: python, perl

I have a perl script that sorts files from one incoming directory into other directories on a Ubuntu server.
As it is now I'm running it as a cron job every few minutes but it can give problems if the scripts starts while a files is getting written to the incoming dir.

A better solution would be to start it when a file is written to the incoming dir or any sub dirs.

I'm thinking I could run another script as a service that will call my sorting script whenever a dir change occur, however I have no idea of how to go about doing it.

Comment: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki

Comment: I have a problem related with this: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/issues/128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can use pyinotify library: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

For watching subdirectories use rec=True in add_watch() invocation. Complete example monitoring /tmp directory and its subdirectories for file creation:

```
import pyinotify

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        # Processing of created file goes here.
        print "Created:", event.pathname

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, EventHandler())
wm.add_watch('/tmp', pyinotify.IN_CREATE, rec=True)
notifier.loop()
```